# Sorting by day of the week on a seaborn violin plot

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, seaborn

I am working with [this dataset](http://www3.dsi.uminho.pt/pcortez/forestfires/) I'm trying to create a violin plot of the area different fires burnt down against the day of the week it happened on.

here's my code

```
sns.catplot(x="day", y="transformed_area", kind="violin",data=df)
```

here's the result
[image: plot]

It looks good except the days are in the wrong order. How would you put them in the right order?

Comment: You can use `sns.catplot(...., order=['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'])`.  Alternatively, you can fix an order on the column in the dataframe via `df['x'] = pd.Categorical(df['x'], ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'])`.

Comment: There's an exact example of this in the documentation if you look https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html

Comment: thanks! I didnt see that page